# CNN to output percentage of 2 class

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, transfer-learning

i'm a beginner in the argument. I have this problem: I have to classify the percentage of 2 class in each frame of a video.
I created a small dataset with about 500 images (250 of each class), and a CNN with these layers:

```
model = tf.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu',input_shape=(224,224,3)))
model.add(tf.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(tf.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(tf.layers.Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(tf.layers.Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(tf.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(tf.layers.Dense(2,activation='sigmoid'))
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.00001), metrics=['accuracy'])
```

1)It's better for the problem use **binary_crossentropy + sigmoid** or **binary_crossentropy + softmax**?

2)Then it's better to use transfer **learning/fine tuning** or build CNN from scratch like this?

3)I'm using ImageDataGenerator for **DataAugmentation** because the small dataset, it's right?

4)Which values I can use for batch_size, steps_per_epochs,learning_rate...I noticed that the model accuracy goes early to 1.0 with val_accuracy, and in the predictions doesn't return the correct percentage of each class, but return values like [9.999e-1 4.444e-5]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Since, yours is a binary classification, go with sigmoid. Softmax is for multi-class (>2).
2. It is always better to use transfer learning. Go with VGG16, ResNet, Inception and others.
3. Yes, in case of small datasets, data augmentation helps a lot.
4. You need to use one neuron in the last layer rather than 2. Since, in one neuron, if value is greater than 0.5, it will be considered as class 1 otherwise 0. If you want to stick with two neurons, then, for getting your answer, you should take `np.argmax` of the prediction, in the example you have given, `pred = [9.999e-1 4.444e-5]`, the predicted class is 0, as pred[0] > pred[1].

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm ok on the first 3 answers, but in the 4th aybe I did not say it clear enough: I want that the model return me 2 values, each value is the percentage of the class in the image(eg. Rocks/Sand 0.78 0.22)

Comment: So, you should stick the original setup then. First percentage = (pred[0] / (pred[0] + pred[1])) * 100 and Second percentage = (pred[1] / (pred[0] + pred[1]) )* 100. Please accept the answer if you are satisfied with it.